Two way communication with new window, different domain
I am new to javascript and not sure if googling it correctly. Is there any way how to open any website (not owner of that document) from main application (I am owner of this document) -> inject javascript code and retrieve the output of that code. So My app -> injecting js code to any webpage -> retrieving data from diff domain webpage to my app.
I can do this 2 way communication for same domain but cannot figure it out how to do it for diff domain.
Thanks.

You can't inject code into a page running in a different domain.

You cannot access the window from another domain for security reasons. If the website of that domains allows it, you can communicate with it with window.postMessage(), but that's communication, not code injection.
